# Using UIAutomation in iOS to click on the buttons on the tab bar

Tags: user-interface, ios4, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I have a tabbar in my application and I have to write a JavaScript file to click on the buttons on the tab bar but the problem is I can't find any relevant information about tab bars and `UIAutomation`.

There are 4 buttons in my tab bar, I am not able to figure out how should I take the reference of my tab bar in the JavaScript file I have to write, for the `navigationbar` I have used

```
navBar = mainWindow().navigationBar();
navBar.leftButton().tap();
```

But I cant find anything similar for the tab bars.

Answer (score 3):

You're writing about tab bar and trying to access it through navBar.

Try this code:

```
var tabBar = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().tabBar();
var tabButton = tabBar.buttons()["First"];  
// Tap the tab bar !
tabButton.tap();
```

Tutorial => http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/04/08/ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation